How to determine the optimal lag length in time series?
I am a beginner in time series analysis, and I am always having this problem of selecting the optimal lag length for my time series, especially when using machine learning algorithms for the forecasting task. Should I consider ACF or PACF? And for what threshold?

If you are mainly interested in forecasting, then please do add that tag. A lag length that is "optimal" for forecasting accuracy is not necessarily the same as an "optimal" lag in terms of "the highest chance of choosing the true underlying data generating process" (assuming such a one even exists and is ARIMA), or in terms of "lowest expected squared error of parameter estimates".
For forecasting in particular, you may be interested in the resources listed here: Resources/books for project on forecasting models
Again for forecasting, your best bet is likely to use an automated ARIMA order selection method, like the one implemented in the forecast and fable packages for R, and AFAIK reimplemented in Nixtla's Python modules. These tools use a grid search over models and information criteria, together with statistical tests for whether or not to use differencing or seasonal differencing. ACF/PACF is not trivial to use, especially for the non-expert: Selecting ARIMA orders by ACF/PACF vs. by information criteria. (Plus, whether an ARIMA model is actually the way to go will very much depend on your actual situation. ARIMA is usually not a very strong contender in terms of forecast accuracy.)

Your parenthetical remark in the first paragraph seems to presume the OP is working with ARIMA, but that has not been specified by the OP.

@RichardHardy: absolutely true. However, I would be positively astounded if a "beginner in time series analysis" had seen ACF/PACF in any other context.

Sure. I just think your answer would be more correct / make more sense with the assumption being explicit instead of implicit.
